# This-pointer and linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, this

Stroustrup writes in "Design and Evolution of C++":

> Without `this` or some equivalent mechanism, member functions cannot be used for linked list manipulation.

What does he mean by that and is it still relevant with modern compilers?

I usually find it hard to describe a valid use-case for the  `this`-pointer since the compiler usually does the right thing without using  `this`.

Comment: Do you mean why `this->` is needed in the implementation of std::list (Don't expect us to know C++ books by heart not even Bjarne's books)? That is to let the compiler figure out the difference between a free function template and a member function of a class template.

Comment: You are talking about the use of the `this` keyword in a C++ program. I'm not sure the Bjarne is doing the same. He might be talking about the concept of the this pointer, which is there whether or not you actually use the `this` keyword. But more context needed.

Comment: I found the reference. Yes it is still relevant, member functions of C++ classes always need to know which instance of an object they should work on. To be able to reuse compiled code member functions are compiled once and something identifying class instance that function needs to work on needs to be passed to the function. In theory this could be anything unique, but just passing a pointer to the instance/data of an object is just the most efficient. So member functions always get an implicit 1st extra argument -> the pointer to the object.  And this pointer is called `this`

Comment: context is needed to answer this question.

Comment: That's a weirdly specific use case, but I think he's referring to constructs like `that->next = this;`. Without `this`, an object can't refer to itself.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have quoted the whole paragraph. Stroustrup is talking about the keyword and why he had to add it eventually.  *"In every member function, a pointer called t h i s refers to the object for which the member function was called. Stu Feldman remembers that in the very first C with Classes implementation, the programmer couldn't refer directly to t h i s . After he pointed that out to me, I promptly remedied the problem. Without t h i s or some equivalent mechanism, member functions cannot be used for linked list manipulation."*

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what Dr. Stroustrup intended, but imagine a circular linked list. Creating the first one might require you to do something like this:

```
next = this;
prev = this;
```

You also couldn't have parent-child relationships where the child needs a pointer to the parent:

```
Child * child = new Child;
child->parent = this;
```

Nor could you write proper operator= functions, which return *this. And builder patterns also frequently return this (as a reference -- *this). I write my setters like this:

```
Class & setFoo(int value) { foo = value; return *this; }
```

Because then I can do:

```
obj.setFoo(1)
   .setBar(2)
   .setZulu("Hello);
```

(Most people write setters to return void, but I like this style.)

You use `this` a lot. There are callback cases where you need it, or when you want to pass yourself as an argument to calls on other objects.